Why are the results different? What are the effects of 'println'



public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        for (;;) {
            books.add(new Book("book"));
            System.out.println(i++);
        }
    }
}

class Book {
    private String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}




public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        for (;;) {
            books.add(new Book("book"));
        }
    }
}

class Book {
    private String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

Why are the results different?

Runs all the time.
OutOfMemoryError

enter image description here
enter image description here

You cannot persuade me that (2) runs forever.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors..   Copy and paste the relevant text into the question.  (And I would say that your demonstration would be more convincing if you were running the code from the command line rather than in an IDE.)

The difference is speed.
Both of them run out of memory eventually: You are making a thing that takes up some space (namely, a book), and adding it to an arraylist (which itself takes some space), thus ensuring that this thing you made cannot be garbage collected. And you do that, in a loop, forever.
The reason that one does it quickly and the other much more slowly is that a book instance doesn't take all that much space, and System.out.println sends data through a bit of a wild ride that ends up, eventually, emitting characters into that console view in your IDE. println waits for that wild ride - it is as slow as the whole process is, and that process is not particularly efficient. In other words, System.out.println is more or less equivalent to Thread.sleep(10L) (without the benefits of giving the CPU a break). It is vastly slower than the code that doesn't need to wait for that process of getting characters to appear in your IDE's console view.
Hence, the snippet without the sysout statement runs much, much faster, and hence, its 'memory used per minute' rate is an order of magnitude larger. Thus, that one will crash out with an OutOfMemoryError quickly, and the other snippet will also do so, but will take much longer.

Alternative explanation:
I really doubt this is what's happening, but, theoretically, perhaps, possible:
JVMs do hotspot compilation. JVMs do advanced optimization (As in, explaining what it does, how it does it, and when, requires a thousand pages to explain), but only to code that runs a lot (the idea is: 99% of the time is spent on 1% of the code, so, the only code that needs this treatment is that 1%; it's not a good idea to analyse 100% of the code because that analysis is very expensive). Your snippet without the sysout runs continuously and thus the CPU is quite busy, thus, the JVM's behaviour as far as hotspot is concerned is different. The sysout side gives the JVM much more idle time to use to analyse earlier.
Such an analysis might determine that the list is never used, therefore, the book instances aren't used, therefore, that code can be eliminated.
The rules indicate this is allowed ('OutOfMemoryError' is not guaranteed), but, I doubt this happens. One easy way to solve it is to make the for loop condition not necessarily infinite (for example, 'loop as long as System.currentTimeMillis() is positive', or, loop 100 trillion times, which technically isn't infinite - second is better, System.currentTimeMillis() is expensive), then do something that requires the books to still be there, thus, assuring that any hotspot analysis cannot determine 'eh, nobody uses the list nor the books so I can eliminate those lines entirely'.
